# The muddy water leaked into the campus

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

Sometimes, for whatever reason, you need to make a change.

Maybe something inside of you changed, and you want the outside to reflect it.

Maybe you want to change something from the outside in.

Maybe you're just a bit embarrassed.

This happened to someone I know. I hardly recognize them anymore. But to try and understand them I checked what happened with their friends.

> The muddy water leaked into the campus
>
> Phil found refuge in the heights
>
> Virtually countless are hiding behind the letters
>
> The one who cycles replaced his limb to live
>
> The Research stood still and disguised itself as fruit
>
> The underwater vehicle went underground
>
> And my friend is now beyond.

**Who is my friend?**

Hints

#1

> My friend is about 17 years old, but some of his friends are over a 100.

#2

> My friend's friends are not so much his friends as they are simply members of the same category/class.

#3

> The muddy water only sings with its weapons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend is

> Meta, formerly known as Facebook Inc

This whole riddle was solved in the comments by @Mazement @hexomino @fljx and @Amoz.

The riddle is about

> companies changing their name or becoming a subsidiary of a another name.

*The muddy water leaked into the campus*

> Military company Blackwater became Academi.

*Phil found refuge in the heights*

> Philip Morris became a subsidiary of Altria.

*Virtually countless are hiding behind the letters*

> Google (from googol meaning 10^100) became a subsidiary of Alphabet.

*The one who cycles replaced his limb to live*

> The Lance Armstrong Foundation became part of the Livestrong Foundation.

*The Research stood still and disguised itself as fruit*

> Research In Motion became Blackberry.

*The underwater vehicle went underground*

> Pete's Super Submarines changed their name to Subway.

*And my friend is now beyond.*

> Facebook Inc. changed its name to Meta.

Comment: Building on your theme, "Research" might be Cnyb Nygb Erfrnepu Pragre (CNEP="fgbbq fgvyy") juvpu perngrq gur THV vagresnpr gung jnf znqr cbchyne ol gur Nccyr Znpvagbfu. "Qvfthvfrq vgfrys nf sehvg" pbhyq ersre gb CNEP'f snvyrq pbclevtug vasevatrzrag ynjfhvg ntnvafg Nccyr.

Comment: Well done! The final friend must be rot13(Snprobbx, abj pnyyrq Zrgn, zrnavat orlbaq)

Comment: Both of those sound good. I'll add them in.

Comment: @cap good direction, see hint

Comment: To fill in another blank, I'm fairly confident the virtually countless hiding behind the letters are rot13(n cbchyne frnepu ratvar ybbfryl anzrq nsgre n uhaqerq qvtvg ahzore (tbbtby/Tbbtyr -> Nycunorg) )

Comment: Ah, looks like I was too slow, and you worked that one out while I was commenting.

Comment: @cap very nice :) and you're right about it being incomplete too, so I'll give you a bit more time.
There's a more elegant solution to the fruit disguise

Comment: @fljx it helps to know you were thinking the same thing!

Comment: @Dotan thanks. Will keep working on it.

Comment: For the fruity one rot13(Erfrnepu va Zbgvba eroenaqrq gb Oynpxoreel)

Comment: And Phil might be rot13(Cuvyvc Zbeevf juvpu eroenaqrq nf Nygevn), but I can only see a tenuous link from the prefix there to heights.

Comment: Oynpxjngre Npnqrzv is clear now